# Spring Boot: How to avoid too many JPA repositories for each domain class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm building a Spring Boot application containing more than 10 domain classes which need to be persisted in a SQL database. 
The problem is that I need to create an interface for every single domain class, so something like this for each one:

```
public interface BehandelaarRepo extends CrudRepository<BehandelCentrum, Long> {

}
```

Is there any way to decrease the number of repositories by using some kind of design pattern or whatever? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually make it some easier for yourself by using generics the same way Spring Data JPA does it:

```
public interface JpaRepository<T extends Serializable, ID extends Serializable> {
    public <S extends T> S save(S object);
}
```

The trick is that you can use all subclasses, and you're getting that class back as well. I always create one superclass, so I get rid of my ID generic:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class JpaObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    (.... created, last updated, general stuff here....)
}
```

I create my @Entity classes as a subclass from this JpaObject.

Second step: create my super interface for future usage of special queries:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface Dao<T extends JpaObject> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
}
```

Next step: the generic Dao which looks some stupid and remains empty at all times

```
@Repository
public interface GenericDao extends Dao<JpaObject> {
}
```

Now have a sharp look at that save method in CrudRepository / JpaRepository:

```
public <S extends T> S save(S object);
```

Any object extending JpaObject (S extends JpaObject) now can be given as a parameter to all methods, and the returntype is the same class as your parameter.

(Aziz, als het handiger is, kan het ook in het Nederlands uitgelegd worden :P Groet uit Zwolle)

Comment: Thanks!  Groet uit Utrecht :)

Comment: is there a full running example of this solution? Thanks!

Comment: I am getting following exception "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Not an entity: class com.x.x.x.x.JpaObject ". Has anyone faced this problem?

Comment: Save() method is fine since it returns <S extends T> but what about methods like findAll() that return Iterable<T> ?? How can I use the GenericDao with findAll()?

Comment: findAll usually is a way too big query in these cases. You will need a paged result, usually with some special filters, and those I just write in my special interfaces. I guess you can write a findByType<S> in the generic dao, but I never tried it

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had a similar problem. I resolved it by creating new layer, namely
RepositoryManager (or ModelService) singleton that had all the repo interfaces and methods that used them.

If you want you can implement generic save method (then call that class ModelService) that resolves model types through reflection and chooses the corresponding repository.

It was also handy for decoupling cache implementation (I used spring cache).

Comment: This looks interesting.Can you give some information? How you included all repositories in singleton?Can you show your high level code snippet?