# Hibernate + MySQL Best practices for reporting data

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, hibernate

I am creating a webapp in Spring Boot (Spring + Hibernate + MySQL).

I have already created all the CRUD operations for the data of my app, and now I need to process the data and create reports.

As per the complexity of these reports, I will create some summary or pre proccesed tables. This way, I can trigger the reports creation once, and then get them efficiently.

My doubt is if I should build all the reports in Java or in Stored Procedures in MySQL.

Pros of doing it in Java:

- More logging
- More control of the structures (entities, maps, list, etc)
- Catching exceptions
- If I change my db engine (it would not happen, but never know)

Cons of doing it in Java:

- Maybe memory?

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Java. Though both are possible. It depends on what is most important and what skills are available for maintenance and the price of maintaining. Stored procedures are usually very fast, but availability and performance also depends on what exact database you use. You will need special skills, and then you have it all working on that specific database.

Hibernate does come with a special dialect written for every database to get the best performance out of the persistence layer. It’s not that fast as a stored procedure, but it comes pretty close. With Spring Data on top of that, all difficulty is gone. Maintenance will not cost that much and people who know Spring Data are more available than any special database vendor.

You can still create various “difficult” queries easily with HQL, so no block there. But Hibernate comes with more possibilities. You can have your caching done by eh-cache and with Hibernate envers you will have your audit done in no time. That’s the nice thing about this framework. It’s widely used and many free to use maven dependencies are there for the taking. And if in future you want to change your database, you can do it by changing like 3 parameters in your application.properties file when using Spring Data.

You can play with some annotations and see what performs better. For example you have the [@Inheritance](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html) annotation where you can have some classes end up in the same table or split it to more tables. Also you have the [@MappedSuperclass](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) where you can have one JpaObject with the id which all your entities can extend. If you want some more tricks on JPA, maybe check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831907/spring-boot-how-to-avoid-too-many-jpa-repositories-for-each-domain-class) with my answer on how to use a superclass and a general repository.

Answer (score 1):

> As per the complexity of these reports, I will create some summary or
>   pre proccesed tables. This way, I can trigger the reports creation
>   once, and then get them efficiently.

My first thought is, is this required? It seems like adding complexity to the application that perhaps isn't needed. Premature optimisation and all that. Try writing the reports in SQL and running an execution plan. If it's good enough, you have less code to maintain and no added batch jobs to administer. Consider load testing using E.G. jmeter or gatling to see how it holds up under stress.

Consider using querydsl or jooq for reporting. Both provide a database abstraction layer and fluent API for querying databases, which deliver the benefits listed in the "Pros of doing it in Java" section of the question and may be more suited to the problem. This blog post [jOOQ vs. Hibernate: When to Choose Which](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/03/24/jooq-vs-hibernate-when-to-choose-which/) is well worth a read.

Comment: Nice answer. About your question, this is required. Is required because all the data is in some tables, and I need to create a report mixing all of these ones and create totals, and percentages, etc.
I've never heard about JOOQ. Is it possible to mix it with Hibernate? I mean, to have Hibernate for all my CRUD operations and then maybe use JOOQ only for reporting?

Comment: Could you perform joins and use aggregate functions to create totals and percentages and avoid creating this extra table? It sounds like what you want can be done in a SQL statement. Yes, querydsl and JOOQ are separate frameworks which can be used in addition to Hibernate. Have a look at querydsl-jpa http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html#jpa_integration which works in combination with Hibernate.

Comment: You can just use pojo’s, keeping your subresults in your memory. No need to have actual tables (but you can always map them on entities). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419305/spring-data-jpa-getting-no-aliases-found-in-result-tuple-error-when-executing/42419939#42419939 on how to use non-entity pojo’s in your JPA repositories